# How do I reduce the threads per process limit for an ISAPI app under IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, python, threads, isapi

I have a python WSGI application running under an ISAPI extension in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008. I would like to increase the number of worker processes (which I know how to do) and reduce the number of threads per process (which I don't). I'm concerned that I may have too much contention for the GIL.

I have seen instructions such as [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050.aspx) for modifying threads per process, but that setting doesn't seem to affect my application - my w3wp processes still show the same number of threads. I assume this is because that setting only affects ASP.NET applications, which this is not.

I'm aware that I could switch to a different python runtime such as stackless or twisted. Or a different host such as Apache. Or a different OS such as Linux. I can't afford those tasks right now, and am looking for some shorter-term tuning.